# Rename .log file on local pc and copy it

Tags: powershell, rename

I need a Powershell solution where I can rename a specific log file on a pc to computername.log and then copy it to a share. The copy part I can handle, but it's the renaming of a file to [computername].log part that's bothering me.

So:
Rename xxxx.log file to [computername].log
Copy [computername].log to share

Sorry if it's basic, but I'm new at powershell.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. This is basic but, that's alright. Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Why not copy and rename in a single operation? The [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.1) cmdlet can do this; in fact, Example 4 is almost exactly your use case.

```
Copy-Item -Path xxxx.log -Destination \\Share\ComputerName.log
```

should do the trick, with the obvious substitutions.

Comment: Sorry. Wasn't clear enough in my original post. On the share, the same log file (with the same name) will be there from maybe300 pc's. So I need to rename the file locally to a unique name (hense the computername variable), before copying it over to a share. Does that make sense?

Comment: That's exactly the point - you _don't_ have to rename before copying; the copy as shown above _is_ effectively the rename. For example, if the computername is stored in `$cn`, and you're using UNC pathnames to copy from `C:\LOGS\CHOCOLATE.LOG` to the share named `SHARE`, you could use `Copy-Item -Path "\\$cn\C$\LOGS\CHOCOLATE.LOG" -Destination "\\SHARE\$cn.LOG"`. You can also wrap that single statement into a `ForEach` loop to run through all 300-odd workstations, e.g., `ForEach ($box in $allboxes) {Copy-Item -Path \\$box\C$\LOGS\CHOCOLATE.LOG -Destination "\\SHARE\$box.LOG"}`.